# Using javaScript setInterval within custom game class

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

Coming from Java I'm trying out javascript and html5, but I think I'm trying to write as if I was still in java and it's really not working. The issue in this code gfx in the Game class is undefined when the update function is called by setInterval.

Here's the code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("game");
    var game = new Game(canvas, 60);
    game.start();
}
```

class Renderer {

```
constructor(canvas) {
    this.ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
}

resize() {
    this.ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    this.ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}

//to do
```

}

class Game {

```
constuctor(canvas, fps) {
    this.gfx = new Renderer(canvas);
    this.fps = fps;
}

start() {
    var self = this;
    this.intervalID = setInterval(function(){ self.update() }, 1000 / this.fps)
}

update() {
    this.gfx.resize(); // error undefined

    //to do
}
```

}

Comment: What is the result after the class instantiation? Is that Renderer successfully returning a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@luctowers: Here is the answer

```
 class Renderer {

    constructor(canvas) {
    this.ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    }

    resize() {
    this.ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    this.ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    }
}

class Game {
    constructor(canvas, fps) {
    this.gfx = new Renderer(canvas);
    this.fps = fps;
    }

    start() {

    this.intervalID = setInterval(()  => this.update, 1000 / this.fps)
    }

    update() {
    this.gfx.resize(); // error undefined

    //to do
    }
}
```

### Two things were wrong:

1. You have a typo on the Game class,you misspelled the word
       constructor
2. On the start function, the scope of **this** was wrong. I use the arrow
   function to keep the same scope inside the class.

Give it a try!